# Outputting JSON data into props pulled from FireBase database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-state-management

I am attempting to output a set of a data from a real-time database into html elements, I have no issues in taking the data from the server and using setState to save the data. I have a custom HTML object from a functional Component that will output props, but I am unable to map the object and the inner objects.

Here is the code responsible for pulling the data from the database:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('./tasks.json')
      .then(response => {
        const fetchedTasks = [];
        for (let key in response.data) {
          fetchedTasks.push({
            ...response.data[key],
            key: key
          });
        }
        this.setState((prevState, props) => {
          return {
            taskList: fetchedTasks
          }
        } )
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

And this is the data I am pulling from the database. I want to be able to display each item per it's name, id etc.
This is an export of the JSON data from the server, this is the copied into the state of my class component via the axios.get call 'Past.js'

```
    {
      "tasks" : {
        "09182018" : {
          "-LMgzJGM78f0BHbPf8cc" : {
            "hours" : 0,
            "id" : "2018-09-18T14:02:25.022Z",
            "minutes" : 0,
            "name" : "sadflkjdsalkf",
            "seconds" : 2,
            "start" : "2018-09-18T14:02:22.508Z"
          },
          "-LMgzaEYe0tcCjpxOuPU" : {
            "hours" : 0,
            "id" : "2018-09-18T14:03:38.635Z",
            "minutes" : 0,
            "name" : "safd",
            "seconds" : 2,
            "start" : "2018-09-18T14:03:36.353Z"
          }
        },
        "09192018" : {
          "-LMm7EoPnNdQLrZ5Rg62" : {
            "hours" : 0,
            "id" : "2018-09-19T13:59:31.361Z",
            "minutes" : 0,
            "name" : "sadf",
            "seconds" : 2,
            "start" : "2018-09-19T13:59:29.281Z",
            "user" : "placeholder"
          }
        },
        "09212018" : {
          "-LMve6ihcRX_uZfvBcaC" : {
            "hours" : 0,
            "id" : "2018-09-21T10:24:06.504Z",
            "minutes" : 0,
            "name" : "sadfsd",
            "seconds" : 2,
            "start" : "2018-09-21T10:24:03.841Z",
            "user" : "placeholder"
          },
          "-LMvnBBAWaHaBiGW5VMK" : {
            "hours" : 0,
            "id" : "2018-09-21T11:03:44.420Z",
            "minutes" : 0,
            "name" : "hello",
            "seconds" : 14,
            "start" : "2018-09-21T11:03:29.802Z",
            "user" : "placeholder"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I have attempted to run .map() calls on the state with no luck, mapping the nested item throws 'array.map is not a function'. This is the code I have so far:

```
render() {
let outPutItems = [];

if (this.state.loading === false) {
  outPutItems = this.state.taskList.map(array => array.map(item => {
    <CompleteTask
      id={item.id}
      taskName={item.name}/>
  })
)}

return (
  <div className="Past">
    <h1>Past Tasks</h1>
      {outPutItems}
      <button onClick={this.collectTasks}>Log the TaskList!</button>
  </div>
);
}
```

**-UPDATE**

The top three are what I am able to use in react and the bottom is using dummy data and is my desired output from the JSON data above which has been applied to the state from the firebase server.

[top output with map method, bottom using placeholder data from state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fiPc.png)

I am able to output the top three shown with this code, all other code above is the same:

```
      {this.state.taskList.map((outer, index) => (
        <CompleteTask
          taskName={outer.key}
        />
      ) )
    }
```

Comment: I do not see any nested array here (but you'd better post raw response body...it's easier to read than this). Isn't it simply `this.state.taskList.map(item => <CompleteTask ...`

Comment: apologies, have changed some of the description, the main issue I have is that the task object is pulled from firebase wit ha unique object id such as: LMm7EoPnNdQLrZ5Rg62. I am unsure as to how I can access the entries inside that object.

Comment: Ah OK! Well, you need to first extract tasks grouped by date (I assume): `Object.keys(this.state.taskList).map(dateGroup => /*this.state.taskList[dateGroup] */)` to get them all and then `Object.keys()` for the Firebase IDs. Alternatively you might directly use `Object.entries()` which returns nested arrays with key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Taken from [here](https://daveceddia.com/display-a-list-in-react/). In addition, theres no need to check if `loading == false` before rendering a list. If there is nothing in the list to be rendered, nothing will render. Also, as soon as the list is populated it will reflect in the view.

```
return (
    <div className="Past">
      <h1>Past Tasks</h1>
      {this.state.taskList.map((item, index) => (
        <CompleteTask id={item.id} taskName={item.name}/>
      )}
      <button onClick={this.collectTasks}>Log the TaskList!</button>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: The loading state prop is for use in rendering a spinner later on. 

I tried this code and <Completetask/> renders three children which are all null.

Comment: For rendering a spinner or loading icon yeah you need to check if `loading == true` but you don't need to check if `loading == false` before rendering a list. And im not sure what you mean by ***renders three children which are null***. Seems like a problem with actually getting `this.state.taskList` populated. Try populating `this.state.taskList` with local data and testing it. If it works, you know that your method of getting the actual data isn't working right.

Comment: What I mean is that the correct number of collections is rendered, (you can see in the JSON above there are three dates within 'tasks' that hold unique entries) but they contain no data. key is null and the object is empty, not null, that was incorrect.

The data is in my state, I can see that from the devtools and from console.log() calls. The problem I am having is that I cannot map or spread 'deep' enough into the state array taskList in order to output the above JSON data points such as 'name', 'minutes', 'hours' and 'start'.